# Sandbox=False breaks OAuth in Evernote Application

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I have this app that I've built, which scrapes recipes and adds them to evernote. [Link here](https://github.com/StathisKap/EverList). In the EvernotePy folder, there is a python3 script called Add_to_Evernote.py that interfaces with the API. When I have `Sandbox = True`, then it works like normal, but when I turn `Sandbox = False` it breaks when trying to call the function `client.get_authorize_url()`. I just received an email today saying that my API-Key got activated for their production servers, so Idk what' wrong.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                            
File "./EvernotePy/Add_to_evernote.py", line 69, in <module>                                                                                                                  
webbrowser.open(client.get_authorize_url(request_token))                                                                                                                  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/evernote3-1.25.0-
py3.8.egg/evernote/api/client.py", line 58, in get_authorize_url                                            KeyError: 'oauth_token'
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too,happened it was because though I changed the sandbox to FALSE I didn't redeploy the app. so make sure after changing the sandbox value the app is redeploy so the changes takes effect